# Battletech novel focusing on ComStar faction

Tags: story-identification, novel, battletech

The writing on the back of this novel speaks of the faction called ComStar, that it believes itself will one day unite the Inner Sphere under its own banner. There is an implication that ComStar claims to support the other Inner Sphere nations but is keeping many secrets from them and pursuing its own agenda- IIRC the top of the blurb says something like "Comstar- Heroes or Traitors"?

I seem to recall the front cover depicts two or more battlemechs fighting, but that might not help much, seeing as that's a fairly common illustration on *BattleTech* book covers.

Comment: https://www.sarna.net/wiki/ComStar

Comment: @Nu'Daq any updates? Was the suggested book the one you were looking for or shall we keep searching?

Comment: @Jenayah I've been too busy with other stuff to look for a copy, I'll let you know if I ever find one.

Comment: Okay, no worries :)

Answer (score 5):

*Lost Destiny* (1991)?

From [sarna.net](https://www.sarna.net/wiki/Lost_Destiny):

> With secret aid from ComStar—the Terran-based sect that serves as the keeper of the Inner Sphere's technological secrets and controls interstellar communication—the Clans' BattleMech warriors have been incredibly successful in their campaign of invasion. But **ComStar has its own reasons for giving aid to the enemy, and if its strategy proves successful, the Inner Sphere worlds will be finally be reunited under ComStar's rule.**
>
> Yet neither the Clans nor the Great Houses of the Inner Sphere are ready to become ComStar's puppets. And within ComStar's upper echelon a new power struggle is about to begin. As the Clans continue their inward drive, with Terra itself as their true goal, can **ComStar mobilize the Inner Sphere's last defenses—or will their own internal political warfare provide the final death blow to the empire they are sworn to protect?**

[This back blurb](https://www.iberlibro.com/primera-edicion/BATTLETECH-Lost-Destiny-Blood-Kerensky-Saga/18122687196/bd#&gid=1&pid=2) has the tagline

> Humanity's only hope is the Inner Sphere's most powerful traitor.

---

Found by browsing [Wikipedia's list of *Battle tech* novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BattleTech_novels) for `comstar`, the blurb looked like a match:

> And behind it all, ComStar lurks, ready to betray their Clan allies for the chance to fulfill their destiny as the saviors of humanity.